# C: storing a void pointer function in a char array with strcpy

Tags: c, arrays, void

I use a function

```
void * getCapabilities(...)
```

that returns other functions, depending on the given parameter.

Those functions can have different return types, hence, why I return `void *`.
On of those functions is as follows:

```
void * getPeripherals(){
    UInt8 periphs[] = {21,22,23,24,25,26};
    return periphs;
}
```

I'd like to store this in a char array like so:

```
char cap_periph[7];
strcpy(cap_periph,  (char *)getPeripherals());
print("[CL] res_device_capabilities_get_handler. cap_periph[0] %u  cap_periph[5] %u \n", cap_periph[0],cap_periph[5]);
```

However, what is printed is bogus (85 and 0, respectively).

I am doing something wrong, but unsure of what. Can you help?

Comment: `periphs` inside `getPeripherals` has automatic storage, local scope..... You cannot return its address. Otherwise is **Undefined Behavior**

Comment: Arrays aren't NULL byte terminated, so strcpy won't work on them.

Comment: Void doesn't mean any. Very bad design, sorry.

Comment: @vulkanino void* means any return pointer type, I'm unsure as to why you would say it doesn't mean any?

Comment: Technically, it is not returning a pointer to an object with automatic duration that causes UB; rather, it is afterward *using* that pointer as if to access the no-longer-existing object to which it initially pointed.

Comment: Managed to fix it using your guys advice and the duplicate. Basically by defining periphs outside and returning that.

Thanks for the help!